# Can we use bidrectional search for directed+cyclic graphs?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

What is an efficient way to find the shortest path from one node to another node in a large graph (with around 300k nodes)?

I have tried Breadth first search and Depth first search, but they are not fast enough for my case.

I have heard about Bidirectional search, but it works only for undirected graph.

Comment: try [A* search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/)

Comment: [This review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05140.pdf) may be helpful.

Comment: In theory, you can't beat BFS/DFS since they run in linear time. But could you please clarify whether your graphs has weights?

Comment: @Juho I have the coordinates of the nodes, so it might be useful if I want to find path with shortest distance. But in my case any path is possible (I preferred implementation time)